# Calling Fortran subroutine in Python returns 'NoneType'

Tags: python, r, fortran, fortran77, f2py

I want to write a Python package containing the essential features of R's [KernSmooth](https://github.com/cran/KernSmooth) package maintained by Brian Ripley. Most of the code for R's [KernSmooth](https://github.com/cran/KernSmooth) is written in Fortran77 syntax. So basically mimicking what Brian Ripley did in R, my plan is to import the [Fortran subroutines](https://github.com/cran/KernSmooth/tree/master/src) into Python and write the corresponding user interface. As a start, I'd like to put the Fortran77 subroutine *rlbin.f* (code below) inside a Python function.

```
c  Part of R package KernSmooth
c  Copyright (C) 1995  M. P. Wand
c
c  Unlimited use and distribution (see LICENCE).

cccccccccc FORTRAN subroutine rlbin.f cccccccccc

c Obtains bin counts for univariate regression data
c via the linear binning strategy. If "trun=0" then
c weight from end observations is given to corresponding
c end grid points. If "trun=1" then end observations
c are truncated.

c Last changed: 26 MAR 2009

      subroutine rlbin(X,Y,n,a,b,M,trun,xcnts,ycnts)
      double precision X(*),Y(*),a,b,xcnts(*),ycnts(*),lxi,delta,rem
      integer n,M,i,li,trun

c     Initialize grid counts to zero

      do 10 i=1,M
         xcnts(i) = dble(0)
         ycnts(i) = dble(0)
10    continue

      delta = (b-a)/(M-1)
      do 20 i=1,n
         lxi = ((X(i)-a)/delta) + 1

c        Find integer part of "lxi"

         li = int(lxi) 
         rem = lxi - li
         if (li.ge.1.and.li.lt.M) then
            xcnts(li) = xcnts(li) + (1-rem)
            xcnts(li+1) = xcnts(li+1) + rem
            ycnts(li) = ycnts(li) + (1-rem)*y(i)
            ycnts(li+1) = ycnts(li+1) + rem*y(i)
         endif

         if (li.lt.1.and.trun.eq.0) then
            xcnts(1) = xcnts(1) + 1
            ycnts(1) = ycnts(1) + y(i)
         endif      

         if (li.ge.M.and.trun.eq.0) then 
               xcnts(M) = xcnts(M) + 1
               ycnts(M) = ycnts(M) + y(i)
         endif

20    continue

      return
      end

cccccccccc End of rlbin.f cccccccccc
```

I already successfully compiled the Fortran code and imported it into Python.

In the Unix shell I typed

```
f2py -c -m rlbin rlbin.f
```

creating a shared library *rlbin.so* which I imported into Python:

```py
import rlbin
```

```py
print(rlbin.__doc__)
```

Output:

```
This module 'rlbin' is auto-generated with f2py (version:2).
Functions:
  rlbin(x,y,n,a,b,m,trun,xcnts,ycnts)
.
```

```py
print(rlbin.rlbin.__doc__)
```

Output:

```
rlbin(x,y,n,a,b,m,trun,xcnts,ycnts)

Wrapper for ``rlbin``.

Parameters
----------
x : input rank-1 array('d') with bounds (*)
y : input rank-1 array('d') with bounds (*)
n : input int
a : input float
b : input float
m : input int
trun : input int
xcnts : input rank-1 array('d') with bounds (*)
ycnts : input rank-1 array('d') with bounds (*)
```

I specified the input parameters as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

# create random x and y arrays
x = np.ndarray(shape=(2000,), dtype=float, order='F')
y = np.ndarray(shape=(2000,), dtype=float, order='F')

n = len(x)
a = 0.05
b = 0.995
M = 500
trun = 1

xcents = np.zeros(M)
ycnts = np.zeros(M)
```

I checked the data types: *a* and *b* are indeed floats; *n*, *M*, and *trun* are integers; *x*, *y*, *xcnst* and *ycnts* are numpy arrays.

And called the Fortran subroutine

```py
out = rlbin.rlbin(x, y, n, a, b, M, trun, xcnts, ycnts)
```

which executes without error. Similarly, calling *out* does not throw an error but does not return anything either.

`type(out)`however returns `NoneType` and
`print(out)` returns `None`.

I tried the same procedure (compile, import, call) in R and it worked without any problems.

For the ones interested, the corresponding R call would be (taken from the [all.R](https://github.com/cran/KernSmooth/blob/master/R/all.R) script, lines 713-724):

```
out <- .Fortran("rlbin", as.double(x), as.double(y), as.integer(n),
                  as.double(a), as.double(b), as.integer(M),  as.integer(trun), double(M), double(M))
```

I already followed a few tutorials to check if my f2py environment is set up properly and yes, I have no issues calling other Fortran subroutines in Python:

- https://notmatthancock.github.io/2017/02/10/calling-fortran-from-python.html
- https://notmatthancock.github.io/2017/03/07/multiple-modules-with-f2py.html
- https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/courses/moved.PythonFortran/f2py.pdf (tutorial)
  https://git.physics.byu.edu/dfvankom/python-learning/tree/master/python-fortran (data)

So what irritates me is that calling the exact same Fortran subroutine in R using the exact same input parameters works flawlessly. Maybe Python handles the input parameters differently than R does, but I don't see how at this point.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you `import inspect` and then `inspect.getsource(rlbin)` in python?

Comment: Hey Chillie, ```inspect.getsource(rlbin)```throws an error, which has about 500 characters. At the end it says ```OSError: source code not available```

Comment: Well, in python an empty `return` statement returns `None` from a function. Your fortran code seems to have a return statement with no variables/values after it. Can that be why the auto-generated code returns nothing as well?

Comment: I ran the command inspect.getsource(*) with the subroutines of the tutorials I mentioned and they throw the same error ```OSError: source code not available```yet the functions are working properly in Python.

Comment: Good point, I'll look into that!

Comment: Soubroutines in fortran usually modify (some of) their arguments and do not return anything. Could you check whether `xcnts` and `ycnts` are changed after the call?

Comment: Thank you so much [nicola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987294/nicola) for the hint! ```xcnts``` and ```ycnts``` have indeed changed after the call. That's what I needed.

Comment: @Chillie the return statement in Fortran does not return anything. It is simply a command to return to the calling program. the subroutine/function output are declared explicitly at the procedure interface